# Build XAML Elements in Runtime, From a List of Data in UWP C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `List<string>` which is below,

```cs
List<string> animeList = new()
{
    "Current",
    "Planning",
    "Paused",
    "Dropped",
    "Custom List"
}
```

I want to build a XAML Element in Runtime from the data available in the above list. To be precise, I want to build a `NavigationViewItem` which is from `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls` Like the below Image,

[image]

The Xaml in this picture is hardcoded and that XAML is Below,

```xml
<winui:NavigationViewItem Content="Anime List" x:Name="animeList">
                <winui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE29B;"
                              Style="{StaticResource FontIconStyle}"/>
                </winui:NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <winui:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                    <winui:NavigationViewItem Content="Current"/>
                    <winui:NavigationViewItem Content="Planning"/>
                    <winui:NavigationViewItem Content="Paused"/>
                    <winui:NavigationViewItem Content="Dropped"/>
                    <winui:NavigationViewItem Content="Custom List"/>
                </winui:NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
            </winui:NavigationViewItem>
```

Here the winui xml namespace is below,

```xml
xmlns:winui="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
```

Here, instead of hardcoding the `NavigationViewItem`, I want to build the `NavigationViewItem` from the above `animeList` in the Runtime. How can I do it.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `NavigationViewItem` to your list of items using the `MenuItemsSource` property:

```
<NavigationViewItem Content="Anime List"
                    MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind animeList}">
    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE29B;" Style="{StaticResource FontIconStyle}"/> />
    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

There is no reason to loop explicitly.

Comment: Here, the list should be List<winui.NavigationMenuItems> right??

Comment: No, `List<string>` just as in your example.

Comment: Then how can I add Content and Name to the NavigationViewItem??

Comment: You don't need to. The strings should be display. Don't you see them?

Comment: It's visible, but I want to name each element to reference the navigation...

Comment: You can't reference them as variables unless you define the items in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a loop, and for every item, you create a new NavigationViewItem

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    foreach (string anime in animeList)
    {
        animeNavigationViewItem.MenuItems.Add(
            new winui.NavigationViewItem
            {
                 Content = anime
            });
    }
}
```